# Creating a table of data submitted on form submit using ajax without saving the data in the database. - Drupal8

Tags: drupal-8

Here is the requirement that I need to achieve in Drupal8.

[Add user email and show it in a table format row wise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvcKZ.png)
The user will enter the email and click on the Add button. Then the added emails will be shown in a table format just below the form with remove link. It will be a ajaxified form.

Below is the code that I have used.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {


    $form['email'] = [
        '#type' => 'email',
        '#placeholder' => $this->t('Enter Email address To Add'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    ];


    // Attach Ajax callback to the Submit button.
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Add'),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' =>  '::ajaxAddEmailRow',
            'event' => 'click',
            'wrapper' => 'email-row-wrapper',
    ),
    ];


    $header = [
        'email' => t('Email'),
        'accounttype' => t('Account Type'),
        'permission' => t('Permission Level'),
        'operation' => t('Operation'),
      ];
  // For testing only.
    $rows[0] = array(


            'email' => 'test1@gm.com',
            'accounttype' => 'account',
            'permission' => 'permission',
            'operation' => 'operation',


        );

        $form['email_rows'] = [
            '#type' => 'table',
            '#header' => $header,
            '#rows' => $rows,
            '#prefix' => '<div id="email-row-wrapper">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            '#empty' => t('No users found'),
        ];


    return $form;
}
```

Any help or guidance highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So what is your question? What did you try, and what happened?

Comment: Hi @MrBeanBremen thanks for looking into. So what did I try? - I created a form with ajax submission and I am able to show the entered value in the wrapper of that ajax. However I am confused how I will keep on saving the email entered by user and show it in the table format as shown in the image.

Comment: There is a full tutorial for [Drupal 8 ajax forms here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms)